# AWS lamda parser not parsing multipart form data

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

I want to parse the attachments in aws lamda and store them in S3 bucket. I have configured my api gate-way and added content-type as "multipart/form-data". I am using "aws-lambda-multipart-parser" which is giving empty response

```
    let results = multipart.parse(event, true);
    console.log(results);
```

I tried to log the event.body and it's giving a long string
here is the image of request and response
[image]